# docker cp command get system error

Tags: centos, docker, glibc

```
root@CentosWebServer opt]# docker export acf -o test.tar
Error response from daemon: Error exporting container acf: error processing tar file: docker-tar: relocation error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2: symbol __libc_readline_unlocked, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
: exit status 127
```

Docker version `19.03.0`, build `aeac9490dc`

ldd (GNU libc) `2.23`

CentOS `7.6`
Kernel `Linux 4.4.186-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64`